# Start sharepoint list workflow 2010 platform from sharepoint 2013 workflow platform

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have two workflows, one of them with SharePoint Workflow 2010 platform to send email to external users, and the other is an SharePoint Workflow 2013 platform.

So, I need to start 2010 Workflow from 2013 Workflow bit i get the following error:

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to http://win-r9ic5tcuftv:46963/Consejo/_vti_bin/client.svc/SP.WorkflowServices.InteropService.Current/StartWorkflow Correlation Id: f9b6c585-4ea5-6ec6-bf8e-127b6162b46c Instance Id: f66f7278-2519-4a01-852e-c6f1ad88d274

And this:
The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'StartWorkflow'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use correct HTTP method to invoke the resource

I tried using System Account and other users with priviledges to colaborate into the list, and it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

[This post on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0cdc4a08-b327-460c-9a9c-b9bf18ce1abd/large-list-unable-to-use-workflow-interop?forum=sharepointcustomization) has some related information.

The issue may be related to starting a 2010 workflow from a 2013 workflow in a list or library that contains many thousands of items- specifically, the Interop service seems to have a hard time with more-than-triple-digit ID numbers.